# How to avoid "Infinite glue shrinkage found in a paragraph." error with enumitem and nameref

Tags: errors, enumitem, nameref

There seems to be a problem when combining the enumitem and nameref package. With the code below I get the error:

> ! Infinite glue shrinkage found in a
>   paragraph.

I already checked the package documentation but neither package mentions the other as problematic in combination.

Removing the enumitem package gets rid of the error, but I need that package elsewhere in the document. This also shows the result that I am after, i.e. a cross-reference with the item label "Label".

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item [Label\label{Ref}] Text
\end{description}

\begin{itemize}
\item \nameref{Ref}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure `\item [Label\label{Ref}]` does what you think it does. Changing `\nameref` to `\ref` (to make it compile) we find this in the aux: `\newlabel{Ref}{{}{1}{\enit@align {\enit@format {Label\label {Ref}}}}{}{}}` I'm not sure those commands are meant to be used outside `\item[...]` of a `description` env.

Comment: `\item[Label]\label{Ref}`

Comment: @egreg it still gives no output for `\nameref`, but I don't think it would ever had anyways

Comment: @daleif When I remove the enumitem package it does what I want it to do, i.e. show a cross-reference with "Label". Is that not what is to be expected?

Comment: @egreg Unfortunately, that gets rid of the error but does not show a cross-reference with "Label" as it does when I remove the enumitem package. I have added the expected result to the description of the question.

Comment: That is probably a lucky fluke, generally `description` does not provide things that are referable. `nameref` may inject stuff into `description` but `enumitem` has its on separate implementation. Perhaps make a feature request for `enumitem`

Comment: @daleif Happen to know where to make such requests?

Comment: Well if you read the `enumitem` manual (hit: it is on the first page)

Comment: @daleif `enumitem` has no fault in this. It's rather `gettitlestring`. See https://github.com/ho-tex/gettitlestring/issues/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nameref` package uses `gettitlestring` that has code to support `enumitem`, but it is incomplete: it only manages `\enit@format`, but not `\enit@align`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\GTS@PredefinedLeftCmds{%
  \GTS@TestLeft\enit@align\GTS@Cdr % package enumitem
}
\g@addto@macro\GTS@DisablePredefinedCmds{%
  \let\enit@align\@empty % package enumitem
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item [Label\label{Ref}] Text
\end{description}

\begin{itemize}
\item \nameref{Ref}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the fix, the `.aux` file contains

```latex
\newlabel{Ref}{{}{1}{\enit@align {\enit@format {Label\label {Ref}}}}{}{}}
```

With the fix,

```latex
\newlabel{Ref}{{}{1}{Label}{}{}}
```