# How to fix error "LaTeX mark Error: Infinite shrinkage found in 'column'." in overleaf

Tags: spacing, sectioning, errors, underfull

I encounter this error, happening at least 6 times in my document. It happens either at the end of a section (e.g. on the line where I have `\section{Related Works}`) or at the end of paragraph before an equation (e.g.
`... is calculated by the formula: \begin{equation}` ), and also at the end of the document `\end{document}`.
But I also have ends of sections and many equations where this does *not* occur.
I also noticed the warning "Underfull \hbox" on every section that comes before the problematic error point.
The compiled pdf file looks fine, but I cannot create a submission file for my article using overleaf without fixing the errors.

I tried:

- adding `\\` or even `\\ \\` at the ends of sections
- Removing any `\\` from any paragraph in the section
- Adding manual empty lines at the line before the new section, then the error was pointing to the empty line
- removing many packages from the beginning of the document that I thought might be relevant, e.g. enumitem
- Removing the `\label{}` command that comes after the `\section{}` command.

All of those didn't affect the errors at all.
When I tried adding `\par` at the end of the section where the error occurs, the same error now occured on the paragraph above the last. When I added `\par` on every paragraph in the section, the error occured on the first line of the section.

**When changing the document type at the beginning from twocolumns to singlecolumn, the errors vanish** but the article is intended to be in two columns.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}

%\usepackage{wacv}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{appendix}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.0}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{codegreen}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{nidanfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{datetime}

\makeatletter
\makeatother

% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    style=ieee,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{export.bib}

%box color commands in table
\newcommand{\gb}{\cellcolor{green!12}}
\newcommand{\ob}{\cellcolor{orange!12}}
\newcommand{\rb}{\cellcolor{red!12}}
\newcommand{\bb}{\cellcolor{black!12}}
\newcommand{\dc}[1]{\textbf{\textsc{#1}}}

% Include other packages here, before hyperref.
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

%\wacvfinalcopy % *** Uncomment this line for the final submission

%\def\wacvPaperID{****} % *** Enter the wacv Paper ID here
\def\httilde{\mbox{\tt\raisebox{-.5ex}{\symbol{126}}}}

% Pages are numbered in submission mode, and unnumbered in camera-ready
% \ifwacvfinal\pagestyle{empty}\fi


\setcounter{page}{1}


\title{text text text text text}

\begin{document}

\author{
author0\thanks{Corresponding author.} \hspace{1cm} author1 \hspace{1cm} author2 \vspace*{1mm}\\
affiliation University \\
{\tt\small author0@email \{author1,author2\}@email}
}
\date{\vspace{-5ex}} % Remove date

\twocolumn[{%
\renewcommand\twocolumn[1][]{#1}%
\maketitle
\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
\begin{center}
    \vspace{-5mm}
    \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \framebox(350,200){}
    \captionof{figure}{text text text text text.}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
}]
%%%%%%%%% ABSTRACT
\begin{abstract}
text text text text text.
\noindent The code is publicly available at: \url{https://address}
\end{abstract}

%%%%%%%%% BODY TEXT
% ------------------ Introduction-----------------
\section{Introduction} \label{introduction}% 
text text text text text. 
text text text text text. text text text text text.
text text text text text. text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.text text text text text. text text text text text.
\section{Related Work} \label{related_work}
\noindent \textbf{subtitle.}`
text text text text text
\end{document}
```

I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526125/how-to-avoid-infinite-glue-shrinkage-found-in-a-paragraph-error-with-enumitem) issue but in my case I don't have the nameref package. Adding it didn't change anything.

---

**Minimal Example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nidanfloat}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[\rule{2cm}{300pt}]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: you will have to provide a small but complete example. Without code it is impossible to debug this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the error is about having infinite shrink, so most likely a mis-placed `\vss` but your decription is about removing `\\ ` or `\par` but neither of those commands should be in document paragraphs at all, and are unrelated to vertical shrink

Comment: If you have `\\ ` at ends of paragraph you will get underfull box _warning_ and you should remove the `\\ ` but that is not the cause of an infinite shrink _error_

Comment: `text text text text text\\\section` never use `\\ ` like this

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you, I added it now

Comment: where is the wacv.sty from? And can you please remove your local picture.

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: File \`wacv.sty' not found.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, I tried without the \\ as well. I don't have any \vss in the document, are there any other similar commands I should look for?

Comment: some code you have not shown is adding infintely shrinkable vertical space. If you do not show the code we can not tell you what to change. the `\\ ` is unrelated but wrong so you should delete it, similarly no document written after 1994 should have `\usepackage{epsfig}` which should also be removed.

Comment: this? https://github.com/wacv-pcs/WACV-2023-Author-Kit/blob/main/wacv.sty

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried with it but couldn't reproduce the error (but it contains a completly outdated eso-pic sty).

Comment: The wacv.sty file was taken from a colleague's project. The error doesn't occur in their project. I removed the lines that depend on the wacv file now

Comment: @AmitGalor  fixed your example so it doe not use local image,you could only get the error in a new latex `! LaTeX mark Error: Infinite shrinkage found in 'column'.`  presumably your co worker has an older system

Comment: you should always use `\captionof` in a box, typically a minipage

Comment: When copying the segment I uploaded here to a new tex document in overleaf I get the error "LaTeX mark Error: Infinite shrinkage found in 'column'." on line 80. It's the same error I got in the original document but in a different location. If the error doesn't reproduce on your compiler does it mean it can be something not in the code itself?

@DavidCarlisle I still don't understand the meaning of this error, so any tips on possible causes of an infinitely shrinkable vertical space are welcome. Thank you for the other corrections as well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, I added minipage as in your answer. I also replaced the local figure with an empty box for the demonstration.  I edited the example accordingly. In the current version I get the shrinkage error on line 97 (at the beginning of section "related works" as in my real document).

Comment: @AmitGalor confirmd here I'll delete my answer for now and return to this later. A more reasonable example with fewer packages would be a lot easier to trace.....

Comment: I added an example with unrelated packages removed

Comment: and in `nidanfloat.sty` we see `\unvbox\@outputbox}% \vss moved from here`   My original guess re `\vss` seems right...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is nidanfloat known to have issues with mark/hook code?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just came to the same conclusion. I didn't know the package, but we should ask Frank.

Comment: @AmitGalor you can probably simply delete `\usepackage{nidanfloat}` but we'll see if the package can be updated.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I made a smaller example we could use for an issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer removing the nidandloat package solved my issue and didn't cause any visible side effects. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm I (as a nidanfloat maintainer) noticed this question just now, but I don't understand why the error happens. Please help ...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @UlrikeFischer and @DavidCarlisle in the comments, the package nidanfloat caused the issue.
Removing `\usepackage{nidanfloat}` solved the issue for me as the package was apparently not needed.